# Might be OR Might have been

Tags: descriptive-grammar, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

The sentence:

> Had the doctor been more careful, my cousin might still have been alive.

In this construction, the two fragments of the sentence are more parallel with their use of `been`. Had he *been* xyz, she might still *have been* xyz.

Would this be better instead:

> Had the doctor been more careful, my cousin might still be alive.

I've read other *might have been* vs. *might be* posts here ([such as this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437373/might-have-been-vs-might-be)) and the architecture is not very clear in situations such as this one here. *Might have been* is a clearer expression if the situation is in the past, but with being alive, it's different -- the qualifying situation is in the past, but being alive is by definition in the 'present'.

Dictionaries such as OED are a bit cavalier in recommending that may and might etc can be used interchangeably these days, which is not helpful. Welcome any guidance!

Comment: It's not a mater of "better". Perhaps the time when the doctor could have been more careful was many decades ago, and your cousin was already quite old back then, so would inevitably have died of old age by now (time of speaking) even if she's survived the doctor's carelessness. All that really matters is whether you're talking about your cousin potentially surviving until ***now***, or simply that she might not have died ***at the time of the medical intervention***.

Comment: Note that ***had*** and ***might*** in your second version imply that these are ***unreal*** "possibilities". You can't really use ***may*** there unless you recast to ***If** the doctor **was** [more] careful, my cousin **may** still be alive* (referring to ***unknown*** possibilities, rather than things we know aren't true).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. Yes, *may* is not applicable here. The contest is between *might have been* and *might be* (alive). This is not so far back in the past that aging and natural death apply. Let's say it's two years ago and the cousin in question was young. Then which one is a better construction?

Comment: If it helps, the cousin might have been alive ***now***.

Comment: Your "hypothetical ***had***" usage is relatively formal / starchy today. Most native speakers would probably just say *If the doctor had been more careful, my cousin might still be alive.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers you answered the question, thank you. If you had posted this as an answer I'd mark it as the right one. It's a comment so I cannot do much. But much appreciate the clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.  One indicates a different time frame from the other.

> Had the doctor been more careful, my cousin might still be alive.

This sentences describes the PRESENT time.  My brother would still be alive NOW.

> Had the doctor been more careful, my cousin might still have been alive.

This sentences describes a PAST time.  My brother would have still been alive at that moment in the past...

This is really [more of a question of the past perfect](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/) than the use of the modal verb *might*.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is what @FumbleFingers above clarified, but it was in a comment. So I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Much appreciated.